# automaticSilentRenew not working for angular oidc-client library

Tags: angular, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm using "oidc-client": "1.10.1" for oidc authentication, below is my configuration for the userManager

```
const settings = {
    
    authority: (window as any).__env.auth.authority, //OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint of the OpenID Provider
    
    client_id: (window as any).__env.auth.clientID, //
    
    redirect_uri: (window as any).__env.auth.redirectUri, //callback URI for the authentication response
    
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    
    scope: 'openid profile api',
    
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    
    silent_redirect_uri: (window as any).__env.auth.silentRedirectUri,
    
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    
    loadUserInfo: true,
    
    post_logout_redirect_uri: (window as any).__env.auth.postLogoutRedirectUri,
    
    silentRequestTimeout: 30000,
    
};
```

The silent renew token calls are not even made, i.e. the user gets logout after token expiration. Am I missing something?

P.S. I want to have the automatic renew of token working, because i tried the token renewal manually and it did work but doesn't seem like a reliable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to check:

- Are renewal messages being sent? Browser tools or a proxy such as Fiddler should give you some info.
- Are you getting any info on errors or timers firing from OIDC client logs? Console output may help.
- Are you processing renewal responses? You usually need to call user manager.signInSilentCallback.
- Or it may just be that no renewal is happening because the token is not within 5 minutes of expiry.

[image]

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

- [Some Working Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)

Note that in my case I did not use a separate HTML file for renewal, and used index.html for both, along with [this startup code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/index.ts).

Comment: I did make it work manually and its working fine, but somehow the automatic renew is not even called , i have closelt looked into the network logs, if it fails i could see that in network, but the request is not even made for the silent renew.

Comment: also server side accesstoken lifetime is only 30min, is this could be a issue?

Comment: I believe renewal will only fire when a token is less than a few minutes from expiry. Try configuring the access token lifetime to be a small value such as 5 minutes and I think you'll see some requests fire - and OIDC Client log entries will show some timer events firing and doing nothing until the token is close to expiry - see above screenshot.